# Meteor observeChanges changed fires more than once

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to invoke `myFunc()` only once when `myArray.length === 3` but it gets fired more than once. How can it be fixed? thx

```
let name = 'john';
myCol.find({name: name}).observeChanges({
   changed: function (id, fields) {
     if (fields.myArr) {
        if (fields.myArr.length === 3) {
            console.log('setting time out for: ' + name); // <--- prints more than once
            let doc = myCol.find({name: name});
            setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
              ddpCall(doc);
           }), 15000);
        }  else if (fields.myArr.length === 4) {
              ddpCall(doc);
        } 
    }
});

let dppCall = function (doc) {
  if (doc.search === 'required') {
      myCol.update({_id: doc._id}, {$unset: {search: ''}});
      ddpConn.call('myFunc', doc);
  }  
}


// some where else in the ddp call code
'myFunc': function () {
    // some logic here which changes the myArr
    myCol.update({name: name}, {$set: myObj, $addToSet: {myArr: myLabel}}); // push myLabel 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you would really need an observer for this. If you have a method writing into this array, why don't you do the whole thing inside the method. If there is any blocking actions like sending sms or email you can use the Meteor this.unblock(). I mention the unblocking because I see you use a long timeout there.

When you avail of the variable with the same name you can skip the declaration:

```
const name = 'john';
myCol.find({name})....
```

the method would be like:

```
'meteormethod' with simple schema or validation etc and inside the method:
 myCol.update({name}, {$set: myObj, $addToSet: {myArr: myLabel}})
 const myArr = myCol.findOne({name}).myArr  // hope 'name' is unique
 if( myArr && myArr.length === 3 ) { fire what you need (with unblock if required) }
end of your method
```

If your required action is server side, your method can call a server side method (which is the typical case for emailing).

Just to keep in mind that $addToSet will not change the length of your array if the value exists in the array [Mongo $addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

I personally prefer to do many things like in the electronic circuits, kind of if this...that just to make sure I do not have to many different logics implemented in a project. I am not sure if the "wireframe" principle may apply to you here.

Also you can simplify your code above by merging the 2 'if' functions:

```
if (fields && fields.myArr && fields.myArr.length === 3 ) { ... }
```

Regards,
Paul

Comment: I have changed the code to reflect the reason for using the timeout which is `myArr.length` may or may never get larger than 3, but just give it 15 seconds to allow its length to change by some ddp logic.

Comment: Not sure if you still have this problem. What I see is that you observe changes to a document found by name in myCol, changes inflicted by  'myFunc' . Then you call a function, ddpCall(doc),  which changes records on the same collection. Would it be possible that you have an overlapping there so that you alter the same document twice, once found by 'name' and then, the same document found by _id : myCol.update({_id:....}) ?